# Invalid metric filter pattern when checking Error in log

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am making the Metrics Filter with CDK 2.

I want to make the filter which find `error` or `Error` or `ERROR` in the log of `fargate`.

These are my scripts.

```
new logs.MetricFilter(this, 'MetricFilter', {
  logGroup: props!.adminLogGroup,
  metricNamespace: 'fargate-metrics',
  metricName: 'fargate-error',
  filterPattern: logs.FilterPattern.exists('{?error ?Error ?ERROR}'),
  metricValue: "1",
});
```

I try this filterpettern however it returns `Invalid metric filter pattern`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the wrong method to create the pattern.

[`FilterPattern.exists`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.FilterPattern.html#static-existsjsonfield) checks for the existence of a JSON field:

> A JSON log patter that matches if the field exists.

> This is a readable convenience wrapper over 'field = *'

If you simply want to check the existence of these strings in the string log, use [`FilterPattern.anyTerm`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.FilterPattern.html#static-anywbrtermterms):

> A log pattern that matches if any of the strings given appear in the event.

```js
logs.FilterPattern.anyTerm('error', 'Error', 'ERROR')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was stick with `exists`wrongly.  I use `logs.FilterPattern.anyTerm('error', 'Error', 'ERROR')` (without `[]`) it works.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Fixed the answer.